# KQL bin on timestamp yields different results than on unix timestamp

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Consider the following table:

```
let fooTable = datatable(ts: long) [
    1655139949044,
    1655053767530,
];
```

It has two unix timestamp values in milliseconds, and the dates are:

```
2022-06-12T17:09:27.53Z
2022-06-13T17:05:49.044Z
```

I want to COUNT() group by the date rounded by week.

One query uses `bin` on timestamp field,

```
let fooTable = datatable(ts: long) [
    1655139949044,
    1655053767530,
];
let bucket_ts = 1m * 10080;
fooTable | summarize count() by bin(unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(ts), bucket_ts)
```

And the second query uses `bin` on Long value.

```
let fooTable = datatable(ts: long) [
    1655139949044,
    1655053767530,
];
let bucket_long = 60000 * 10080;
fooTable | summarize count() by bin(ts, bucket_long) | extend ts=unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(ts)
```

I'm trying to understand why they yield different results - I expected results to be the same (for example, former yields 2 rows, and the latter 1 (as I expected)).

It seems like when `bin` on date types - it groups it by constant time buckets, but on long types it simply floors it to the previous week (based on the relative time).

I want to `bin` on datetime types, to behave like the Long example. How can I do that still using the datetime type?

I guess the easy answer is to convert the datetime to Long, but this solution seems quite messy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unixtime starts with 1970-01-01

```
print unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(0);
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z |

datetime starts with 0001-01-01

```
print todatetime(0);
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z |

Different reference points, different results.

Use [bin_at()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binatfunction) with 1970-01-01 to match the datetime bin to the long bin

```
let fooTable = datatable(ts: long) [
    1655139949044,
    1655053767530,
];
let bucket_ts = 1m * 10080;
fooTable | summarize count() by bin_at(unixtime_milliseconds_todatetime(ts), bucket_ts, datetime(1970-01-01T00:00:00Z))
```

| Column1 | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-06-09T00:00:00Z | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WPywrCQAxF94X%20Q5YdqZChL1vxL1wpUto6yuA8xMmAih/vWKFduDDJIpwb7iXXmzQE3sg7SS1aLZWSTgzWHF1L9tiR%20PAE2TqO4ug6Xv9yJQhO1m67XgnYQJBDhz0h14Cy5sxgH0cQipdFwbO6zmvM83RmWGRVWRUZBnZYfx17P1wEteSCJdewAI64wiBOUS9wXuvuJp8CBusNJQz6B/TStB0lf78ix9I5JYVJ4HWFS%20RhtojNODvG3t3zR8wsAQAA)